# ant target : copying directories and the respective files that are in it

Tags: ant

Suppose I have a directory structure like the following

```
/a/b/testB.xml
/a/c/testC.xml
/a/testD.xml
```

and I want to copy everything inside /a to /build

so that I will have

```
/build/b/testB.xml
/build/c/testC.xml
/build/testD.xml
```

What ant command should I use? I have tried using fileset and it looks like that it only copies the files that are specified in the includes to the todir directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<copy todir="build">
  <fileset dir="a">
    <include name="**/*"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

The docs on `FileSet` are [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).

Comment: I dont think that would copy the testD.xml?

Comment: @denniss: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Actually, do you need the `<include name="**/*">`? A simple `<fileset dir="a"/>` should do the trick since copying everything is the default.